# SetInterval after 15mins

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to setInterval every 15mins but it's not working

```
const timeInterval = 900_000
useEffect(() => {
        const refetch = setInterval(() => {
            console.log("Refetch");
            
        }, timeInterval)
        return () => clearInterval(refetch)
    })
```

But every 10sec, this's working. How can do that with bigger time like 30mins, 1hour?

Comment: The longer time isn't necessarily the issue: some browsers (like all chromium based browsers) will pause intervals in tabs that lose focus.

Comment: You need to have an empty dependency array. Currently, it's deleting and restarting the interval on every rerender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const timeInterval = 15 * 60 * 1000
useEffect(() => {
        setInterval(() => {
            console.log("Refetch");
        }, timeInterval)
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout and setInterval uses milliseconds. 1000 milliseconds is 1 second, so multiply 1000 by 60 to get 1 minute in milliseconds, and then times that by 15 to get 15 minutes in milliseconds.

---

const timeInterval = 1000 * 60 * 15;

---

Comment: 1000 * 60 * 15 is 900000

Comment: that is correct... 900000 milliseconds is 15 minutes...

Comment: So... there's no reason for this answer. OP already used 900k

Comment: They wanted to know how to use other times, figured my answer could help with that.  Admittedly, I'm confused by they're use of underscores (ref: 900_000).

Comment: @kyle4real It's a readability improvement feature called [numeric separators](https://v8.dev/features/numeric-separators).

Comment: thank u, i got it :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your dependency list (which is nothing, `[]`) so, it'll run once on component mount:

```
const timeInterval = 900_000
useEffect(() => {
        const refetch = setInterval(() => {
            console.log("Refetch");
            
        }, timeInterval)
        return () => clearInterval(refetch)
    }, [])
```